# GetEvents from FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm working with [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) I want to create a button that take all the events from the calendar and send them to my database. But when trying to call the **getEvents** method referenced [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) from the calendar object, I cannot get it to work. The method doesn't seem to exist. I get *undefined* method.

Below is a snippet of the initialization of the calendar.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      initialDate: '2020-09-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function(arg) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: title,
            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay
          })
        }
        calendar.unselect()
      },
      eventClick: function(arg) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
          arg.event.remove()
        }
      },
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2020-09-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2020-09-07',
          end: '2020-09-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2020-09-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2020-09-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2020-09-11',
          end: '2020-09-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2020-09-28'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
```

I use the last version of Full Calendar (v5)

When I try to create a button that will get the calendar then retrieve all the events and send it to my database I get error saying that the function doesn't exist.

Here is how I do that :

```js
var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");

/* I can do that since I have my calendar with the id "calendar"
And then I try use the getEvents function 
*/

var events = calendar.getEvents();
/* Show undefined */
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**Super Important Note**: I realized that the function doesn't exist since I try to apply it to the HTML element and not the FullCalendar JS object. So my question is how can I get a FullCalendar JS Object from the HTML element in order to retrieve the events that the user has saved ??

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't show how or where you tried to use getEvents, and you only provided part of the error message. So it's impossible to know exactly what went wrong or what the cause was. The function definitely does exist. So please [edit] the question provide a [mre] of the issue so we can help you more easily without trying to guess what you did wrong. See also [ask], for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. `I want to....take all the events from the calendar and send them to my database`.... why? Surely you should send each event to the database at the time you add it to the calendar (or modify it, or ask for it to be deleted)? That would be more efficient and reliable, and that's how most people would implement it.

Comment: You were right I have edited my question. Now it is more clear I hope.

Comment: As pointed out in the new version, I want a button to send the events. And if we think about it, from an implementation perspective, it would be easier to have a button that send all the events when the user has done with planning the events rather than sending events once at a time they are added. This would imply to implement a database-side deletion.

Comment: It might be easier, but it depends if you already have events on there which existed previously and were loaded from the server when the calendar was shown. If so then it's inefficient to update all of those if they haven't actually changed. Also what if the user takes a long time to complete their updates and someone else loads the calendar in the meantime? They won't see all those pending changes and it might lead to confusion, duplication or unwanted overlaps? Depends on your use cases I suppose, but it's possibly a risk to consider.

Comment: Also what if the user simply forgets to press the button, and leaves the page? Then everything is lost, whereas if you auto-save whenever the user changes something in the UI, there's little/no danger of that happening. But anyway it's up to you of course, that is just my opinion.

Comment: @ADyson Yes it depends on the choice of implementation I choose. I think the both way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because `var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");` fetches the HTML element into which the rest of the calendar's HTML was added by fullCalendar. It does not fetch the fullCalendar instance which was generated by `new FullCalendar.Calendar` when you intialised the calendar. It's the latter which exposes the functions to manipulate the calendar or get data from it.

Notice how you already use that object in your code to call fullCalendar's `render` function, e.g. `calendar.render();`.

(The HTML element object just contains standard functions found on any HTML element, not anything specific to fullCalendar.)

So in summary you need to use the `calendar` variable you created from the `new FullCalendar...` instantiation. If you need access to that outside the scope it was originally declared in (which is the callback of the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler), then one way round that is to make it a global variable, e.g.

```
var calendar; //global variable

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
....
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Then somewhere else in your code, wherever you need it, you can write

```
var events = calendar.getEvents();
```